# How to reduce the higher time complexity brought by DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

After reading the book *Domain-Driven Design* and some characters in the book *Implementing Domain-Driven Design*, I finally try to use DDD in a small service of a microservice system. And I have some questions here.

Here we have the entities **Namespace**, **Group**, and **Resource**. They are also aggregate roots:

[image]

As the picture pointed out, we have many **Namespace**s for users. And in every **Namespace**, we have **Group**s as well. And in every **Group**, we have **Resource**s.

But I have a business logic:

- The **Group** should have a unique name in its **Namespace**. (It is useful that the user can find the **Group** by its name)

To make it come true, I need to do those steps in the application layer to add a group with time complexity `O(n)`:

- Get the **Namespace** by its ID from the Repository of **Namespace**. It has a field `Groups`, and its type is `[]GroupID`.
- Get `[]Group` value by `[]GroupID` value from the Repository of **Group**.
- Check if the name of the new group is unique in the existing **Group**s we get.
- If it does be unique, then use the Repository of **Group** to save it.

But I think if I just use a sample transaction script, I can finish those in `O(lg n)`. Because I know that I can let the field of **Group** name be unique in the database. How can I do it in DDD?

My thinking is:

- I should add a comment in method `save` of the Repository interface for **Group** to let the user know that the `save` will check the name if is unique in the same **Namespace**.
- Or we should use CQRS to check if the name of **Group** is unique? Another question is that maybe a **Namespace** may have a lot of **Group**. Even though we only put the ID of **Group** in the entity **Namespace**, it does cost a lot of space size. How to paginate the data?······ If we only want to get the name of **Namespace** by its ID, why we need get those IDs for **Group**s?

I do not want the DDD to limit me. But I still want to know what is the best practices. Before I know what happens, I try to avoid breaking rules.

---

**My solution**:

Thanks for the answer by @voiceofunreason. I find that it is hard to write code for **set validation** in the domain layer still.

@voiceofunreason tells me that I need consider the real world. I do consider and I am still confused that how to implement it to avoid breaking DDD rules. (Sorry but my question is not do we need the condition or not. My question is **HOW** to make the condition(or domain logic) come true without higher time complexity)

To be honest, I only have a MongoDB serving for storing all data. If I am using Transaction Script, everything is easy:

- Create an index for the name of **Group** to make sure the names are unique.
- Just insert a new **Group**. If the database raises any error, just refuse the request from the user.

But if I want to follow the DDD, and put the logic into the domain layer, I even do not know where to put the logic (it is easy in Transaction Script, right?). It really makes me feel blue. So my solution is:

- Use DDD to split the total project into many bounded contexts.
- And we do not care if we use the DDD or others in the bounded context. So tired I am.
- In this bounded context, we just use Transaction Script.

Is the DDD not well to hold the condition for the set of entities, right? Because DDD always wants to get all data from the database rather than just deal in the database. Sometimes it makes the time complexity higher and I still do not know how to avoid it. Maybe I am wrong. If I am, please comment or post a new answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: Usually uniqueness check is solved with long random IDs, so the chance of ID collision is close to zero and you don't have to check the database by generating a new ID. As of the name what happens if it is not unique? Is it a problem if you merge later with an already existing group which has the same name?

Comment: @inf3rno This is just an example (maybe it is stupid or not). But for this example, the user wants to get the group by its name, like the Linux file system: we can get the file by its path, or we can change its file name, but the file system only cares about its inode. Here user can get the group by its name (and the user does not want that there are two or more groups having the same name of course), but the system only cares about its ID. :)

Answer (score 3):

> The Group should have a unique name in its Namespace.

The general term for this problem is [set validation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304142319/http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/).  We have some collection of items, and we want to ensure that some condition holds over the entire set....

> *What is the business impact of having a failure*

> This is the key question we need to ask and it will drive our solution
> in how to handle this issue as we have many choices of varying degrees
> of difficulty. -- [Greg Young, 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304142319/http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/)

Some questions to consider include: is this a real constraint of the domain, or just an attempt at proofreading?  Are we the authority for this data, or are we just storing a local copy of data that belongs to someone else?  When we have conflicting information, can the computer determine whether the older or newer entry is in error?  Does the business currently have a remediation process to use when the set condition doesn't hold?  Can the business tolerate a conflict for some period of time (until end of day? minutes? nanoseconds?)

(In thinking about this last question, you may want to review [Race Conditions Don't Exist](https://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/), by Udi Dahan).

If the business requirement really is "we must never write conflicting entries into the collection", then any change you make must lock the collection against any potential conflicts.  And this in turn has implications about, for example, how you can store the collection (trying to enforce a condition on a distributed collection is an expensive problem to have).

---

For the case where you can say: it makes sense to throw all of this data into a single relational database, then you might consider that the domain model is just going to make a "best effort" to avoid conflicts, and then re-enforce that with a "real" constraint in the data model.

You don't get bonus points for doing it the hard way.